# How to replace nested blockquote tags with single tag with class?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, blockquote

I inherited several thousand messy HTML files that use repeated `blockquote` tags to  display lines of a poetry.

*Example:*

```html
<blockquote><blockquote>roses are red</blockquote></blockquote><br>
       <blockquote><blockquote><blockquote>violets are blue</blockquote></blockquote></blockquote><br>
    <blockquote><blockquote>this is another line</blockquote></blockquote><br>
    <blockquote><blockquote><blockquote>and this is too</blockquote></blockquote></blockquote><br>
```

For lines of free verse, you’ll see as many as 7-8 block quote tags wrapping a line of text. I want to replace the set of nested `blockquote` tags with a single `<p>` or `<span>` tag and give it a class such as “indent-7” or “indent-8.”

There is unpredictable white space between the `blockquote` tags. Some have spaces between them, some are separated by new lines. I’m thinking Python’s BeautifulSoup is the way to handle this task.

How can I replace the nested `blockquote` tags with a single tag with a class of “n” where n is the number of tags that were nested?

Comment: pls add your css and use the inline snippet function, thx.

Comment: I haven’t written the css to handle the “indent-n” tags yet...

Comment: At this point, I’m not worried about displaying the html. All I need to do at present is to get these nested tags reduced down to one tag with a class.

Comment: Blockquotes should only be used for quotations. If that style isn't enough, consider using a div with a class.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres I know... but I wasn’t the one who made this mess. I’ve got thousands of poems nested in these blockquote tags. As my question says, I want to replace them with span tags with a indent class. However, I’ve got to unwrap them first and record how many layers deep they were wrapped.

Comment: I don't know if this can be done using beautifulsoup, but it can definitely be done using xpath, either directly with an xpath/xquery engine or in python using lxml. If you are interested, I can post an lxml solution.

Comment: @JackFleeting lxml would be great. I was just thinking beautifulsoup might have a method as I was already using it to remove unwanted tags with unwrap().

Answer (score 1):

This how I would approach it with lxml:

(Note that I added a line to the poem, to test for tags separated by space.)

```
poem = """
<doc>
  <blockquote><blockquote>roses are red</blockquote></blockquote><br/>
  <blockquote>     <blockquote>roses are green</blockquote></blockquote><br/>
       <blockquote>
         <blockquote><blockquote>violets are blue</blockquote></blockquote></blockquote><br/>
    <blockquote><blockquote>this is another line</blockquote></blockquote><br/>
    <blockquote><blockquote><blockquote>and this is too</blockquote></blockquote></blockquote><br/>

</doc>
"""

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(poem)
targ = doc.xpath('//text()[normalize-space(.)]')
for t in targ:
    count = int(t.getparent().xpath("count(.//ancestor::*[name()='blockquote'])"))
    print(f'<blockquote indent="{count}">{t}<</blockquote>')
```

Output:

```
<blockquote indent="2">roses are red<</blockquote>
<blockquote indent="2">roses are green<</blockquote>
<blockquote indent="3">violets are blue<</blockquote>
<blockquote indent="2">this is another line<</blockquote>
<blockquote indent="3">and this is too<</blockquote>
```

Just for good measure (and for the benefit of future readers), this is how I would do it with xquery:

```
let $j := <doc>
...text of poem above... 
</doc>

for $targ in $j//text()[normalize-space(.)] 

let $line := $targ/data(.) 
let $count := count($targ/ancestor::blockquote)
return 
<blockquote nested="{$count}">{$line}</blockquote>
```

Same output.

Comment: Thanks, this looks a lot more straightforward than the method I was thinking with beautifulsoup. I’ll give it a try later today and accept this as the answer then.